# How can I configure the maven shade plugin to include test code in my jar?

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, maven-shade-plugin

I use the shade maven plugin to build my project so that all of its dependencies are included in one jar (this makes it easier to run it on Hadoop). Shade seems to exclude my test code by default, which is understandable. Since I would like to run integration tests against my cluster, I am hoping to setup another profile to build a separate jar for this purpose. Is there any way to configure this plugin to also include test code?

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a direct answer, but I ended up adding a test-jar goal to the project that contains the tests and adding another dependency on that project (with the 'tests' classifier) to my shale-built project. Not ideal, but now my shale built jar includes tests as well.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you did?  I'm new to maven and don't understand how you'd add goals to the project or classifiers to the dependencies.

Comment: Add this to the build section of the pom whose tests you want to reuse:
  `<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>test-jar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>`

Depend on that test jar with the "tests" classifier:
  `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>blah</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>`

Comment: @PatrickMarchwiak Could you please show what you did to solve this problem?

Comment: I got a working solution for this topic using the Assembly plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36058365/5606016

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include test classes in Jar created by maven-shade-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307652/how-to-include-test-classes-in-jar-created-by-maven-shade-plugin)

Answer (score 12):

These last couple of answers are messy workarounds for a broken feature at best. The fact of the matter remains that there is a bug in `maven-shade-plugin`. In the meantime I've investigated and root-caused the bug, and created a [patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-284). Now I hope someone at Apache includes it soon and then finally the `shadeTestJar` feature can work like it's supposed to.

Answer (score 9):

With version 2.2 of the maven-shade-plugin, they added a "shadeTestJar" option (see MSHADE-158): http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#shadeTestJar

However, I tried using this and couldn't get it to work. Here's my plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <shadeTestJar>true</shadeTestJar>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The "...-tests.jar" file has no entries, but the main shaded jar looks fine (although it doesn't contain any test classes).

Also, this question duplicates this other question, although the accepted answer isn't real satisfying: [How to include test classes in Jar created by maven-shade-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307652/how-to-include-test-classes-in-jar-created-by-maven-shade-plugin)

Comment: I also tried for a long while this path but couldn't get it working, I ended up using the Assembly Plugin instead and it worked fine, check my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36058365/5606016

Answer (score 5):

I've managed to make it work by adding :

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.1</version>
     <executions>

        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
               <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
               <sources>
                   <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/java/</source>
               </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

      </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: For this to work, any test dependencies need to be made non-test dependencies.

Comment: This solution works for me. Regarding comment "any test dependencies need to be made non-test dependencies" this could be solved by introducing separate shade profile with added all dependencies need for test-classes. Otherwise your shaded JAR will be not workable.

Answer (score 1):

Try `include`ing your test packages like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifactSet>
          <includes>
            <include>org.apache.maven:*</include>
          </includes>
        </artifactSet>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I don't think this will work unless that include encompasses an artifact that includes test code. Even then I would have to add an include for each of my dependencies which is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `maven-shade-plugin` as explained by ~steve-k above is correct, unfortunately due to a bug `shadeTestJar` doesn't work and the resulting test JAR is empty.