# How to include test classes in Jar created by maven-shade-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-shade-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I'm trying to package my test classes in to an executable jar with dependencies using Maven, but I'm struggling to get this right.

This is my pom.xml so far:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.c0deattack</groupId>
    <artifactId>executable-tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>executable-tests</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>cucumber-tests</finalName>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>cucumber.cli.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>info.cukes:*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.c0deattack</groupId>
                        <artifactId>executable-tests</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <type>test-jar</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I execute `mvn clean package` the build creates 3 jars:

- executable-tests-1.0.jar // built by the mvn package phase
- executable-tests-1.0-teststjar // built by the jar-plugin
- cucumber-tests.jar // build by the shade-plugin

`Cucumber-tests.jar` contains the `info.cuke` dependencies but it doesn't contain the `executable-tests-1.0-tests.jar`.

I've done all sorts of things to try and have the test classes included but nothing has worked, what am I missing?

**Edit:** I've pushed my example project to GitHub if any one fancies playing around with it :) https://github.com/C0deAttack/ExecutableTests

Comment: Did you try specifying a classifier explicitly: `<include>com.c0deattack:executable-tests:jar:tests</include>`.

Comment: Hi, yes I tried that too. Even tried using the wildcard support for the <include> but that didn't work either. Really stumped!

Comment: Does it work if you do `mvn clean install` and then `mvn clean package`?  I'm wondering if it's expecting the test jar to be in the local repo?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149130/how-can-i-configure-the-maven-shade-plugin-to-include-test-code-in-my-jar ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved my problem a different way; using two other plugins.

First I use the `maven-dependency-plugin` to get the dependencies and unpack them locally, then I use the `maven-jar-plugin` to create a `test-jar` and include the classes from the unpacked dependencies.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Could you please share your POM file or the code you used for the two dependencies?

Comment: Take a look at my sample project in my Github repo, link in original question above.

Comment: This is a poor answer. Could you please select @A_Di-Matteo' answer? Or at least write a full answer with code.

Comment: Instead of `cucumber.cli.Main`, is there any similar class for testng ?

Comment: For testng, it is `org.testng.TestNG`. This class has the main(). After using this in your `maven-jar-plugin` configuration, you can run the jar using the testng.xml as follows: `java -jar testng-example.jar testng.xml`

Comment: Can we do this with `maven-shade` ?

Comment: With `maven shade`, things work well, if we put classes in the `main` folder.

Comment: @C0deAttack repo is 404 already

Comment: Why is this the selected answer? It doesn't give any clue how to achieve the solution with the mentioned plugins.

Answer (score 27):

Answering late, but got a working solution which may help future visitors of this question.

I succeed on having a fat jar using only one Maven plugin and including:

- The test classes
- The application code classes
- External dependencies required by application code (in `compile` scope)
- External dependencies required by the test code (in `test` scope)

Which basically means a fat jar with the addition of test classes (and their dependencies). The [Maven Jar Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) and its [`test-jar`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) goal would not suit this need. The [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) and its [`shadeTestJar`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#shadeTestJar) option would not help neither.

**So, how to create in Maven a fat jar with test classes and external dependencies?**

The [Maven Assembly Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin) is a perfect candidate in this case.

Here is a minimal POM sample:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>com.sample.TestMain</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The configuration above is also setting a main class defined in test classes (for a quick check whether it works or not, down on the answer). But that's not enough.

You also need to create a [descriptor file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html), in the `src\main\assembly` folder an `assembly.xml` file with the following content:

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>fat-tests</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.class</include>
            </includes>
            <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

The configuration above is:

- setting external dependencies to be taken from the `test` scope (which will also take the `compile` scope as well)
- setting a `fileset` to include compiled test classes as part of the packaged fat jar
- setting a final jar with `fat-tests` classifier (hence your final file will be something like `sampleproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fat-tests.jar`).

#### How can we test it?

Build the jar:

```
mvn clean compile test-compile assembly:single
```

Running from the `target` folder:

```
java -jar sampleproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT-fat-tests.jar
```

We would get the main (from tests classes) executed. The main may invoke others tests or application code (and hence require external dependencies, in both `compile` or `test` scope) and everything would work fine.

---

From such a main, you could also invoke all of your test cases as following:

- Create a JUni test suite
- Add to the test suite the concerned tests
- Invoke the test suite from your plain Java main

Example of test suite:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ AppTest.class })
public class AllTests {

}
```

Note: in this case the test suite is only concerning the `AppTest` sample test.

Then you could have a main class as following:

```
import org.junit.internal.TextListener;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;

public class MainAppTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Running tests!");

        JUnitCore engine = new JUnitCore();
        engine.addListener(new TextListener(System.out)); // required to print reports
        engine.run(AllTests.class);
    }
}
```

The main above would then execute the test suite which will in chain execute all of the configured tests.

Comment: Also, it's not necessary to include a main method. You can launch `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` and specify any or all of your test methods and classes.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky and A_Di-Matteo : Thanks a lot for your answer. It helped and saved a lot of time :)

Comment: @A_Di-Matteo and AleksandrDubinsky - Thanks guys. It works great!