# Include and Run a test class from a jar file java

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have created a maven project, and inside `src/test/java folder`, I've created test classes.
I want to add test classes into my jar file (using maven), and after this, I want to run one of these test classes from command line (using the generated jar file).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want your test classes included in your jar? As a kind of self-test?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, run my test classes from the jar, and this same jar I can run it (run the main class)

Comment: You know that the tests will run by default if you do `mvn clean package` which is the basic idea of unit tests? By default the test classes or in other words the folder `src/test` will never be part of the packaged jar file...

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36047816/5606016) for exactly the same use case, I provided a solution today

Comment: Thank you  sisyphus, khmarbaise, and  A. Di Matteo for your answers!

Comment: # A. Di Matteo, I used your answer, it works pretty fine :)

Comment: Sorry, but in this case the use of Asserts is not useful, we have to create simple classes in this case!

Comment: @Mac you can still use Asserts, check my answer, I updated it