# Manifest.mf and imports

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, urlclassloader

I have the following `dynamodb.jar` structure, where `lib/` has a bunch of `.jar`s. All these nested `.jar`s are needed by `com.mparnisa.dynamodb.table`.

[image]

From another IntelliJ project I am trying to instantiate a class within this `dynamodb.jar`:

```
try {
    File file  = new File("<path>/dynamo.jar");

    URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

    ClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    String resourceModelClassName = "com.mparnisa.dynamodb.table.ResourceModel";

    Class<?> resourceModelClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass(resourceModelClassName);
    Object resourceModel = resourceModelClass.newInstance(); // this works

    String resourceHandlerClassName = "com.mparnisa.dynamodb.table.CreateHandler";

    Class<?> resHandlerClazz  = urlClassLoader.loadClass(resourceHandlerClassName);
    try {
        Object resourceHandlerInstance = resHandlerClazz.newInstance();

    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

The code breaks with

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException
```

This class is within one of the nested JARs and is `import`ed by `com.mparnisa.dynamodb.table.CreateHandler`.

My questions:

1. Do I need to change anything in MANIFEST.MF so that the `import` is resolved properly?
2. Is `URLClassLoader` smart enough to look into the MANIFEST.MF for the `class-path`?