# Spring Autowired fails when run tests with Junit runner

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I'm building a jar-with-dependencies that contains springboot classes and my test-classes too.
my goal is to run my unit-test with Junit runner like this:

```
 java -cp my-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.my.AppTest
```

heres a code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AppTest{

@Autowired
protected Serve1 app;

@Test
public void shouldAnswerWithTrue()
{
    if(app == null){
        System.out.println("IT IS NULL !!!!!!!");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(app.getB()); //prints BBBB!!!
    }

}
```

When running this within maven surefire -  all is great - (BBBB!!!)
but when running with *org.junit.runner.JUnitCore* as described above, the @Autowired app has not being injected and I got:  IT IS NULL !!!!!!!

Comment: Of course. If Spring isn't creating the component, Spring won't inject dependencies into the component. If possible, create the a Serve1 yourself in an `@Before setUp()` method, but if it has transitive dependencies you'll have to have a way to create and inject those yourself (preferably with constructor injection rather than field injection).

Comment: The solution for the problem is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188683/running-spring-tests-from-executable-jar