# How to run Maven Failsafe integration tests from a jar file?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, docker, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have a Spring Boot multi module Maven project, I can run integration tests with:

```
mvn clean verify
```

and it works well. I now want to run the same integration tests from a container and I don't want to embed all the source code in the container.

My question is : how can I run the [Maven Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) without using the source code?

I tried to run the `failsafe:integration-test` goal and setting the [dependenciesToScan](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#dependenciesToScan) parameter, from the command line:

```
mvn failsafe:integration-test -DdependenciesToScan=com.myorg:proj-tests.jar
```

but no tests are found.

P.S.1: I've seen this similar question [Running spring tests from executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188683/running-spring-tests-from-executable-jar). But I don't need to run the tests without Maven. I prefer to run tests from the command line with Maven than adding code or modifying the structure of my project.

P.S.2: I'm using maven-failsafe-plugin 2.22.2 which is the version provided with Spring Boot 2.1.8.

Comment: Why would you like to run IT's inside a container and not the IT's from outside with support of Containers like Testcontainers...

Comment: Our current process it to build Docker images with Jenkins, store them on Nexus, and deploy everything on Kubernetes. It seems straightforward to do the same with integration tests. But maybe [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) is better suited for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> Since version 2.22.0 you can scan for test classes from a project
>   dependency of your multi-module project.

It means the tests (`proj-tests.jar`) must be a dependency of the project. As you cannot have a dependency to the tests jar in the same project where you build them, the solution is to have another module or `pom` file. Example:

```
<groupId>failsafe.use.jar</groupId>
  <artifactId>failsafe-use-jar</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
      <artifactId>proj-tests</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>

   <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

The `proj-tests` is a project dependency and can be created with:

```
 <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
  <artifactId>proj-tests</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
 ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

See [Guide to using attached tests](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html)

To run the integration tests from the container you obviously need all the dependencies installed in the local 
(container) maven repository or deployed in remote. Then you can run with:

```
mvn failsafe:integration-test -DdependenciesToScan=com.myorg:proj-tests
```

Note that the format of the `dependenciesToScan` property is `groupId:artifactId` (you run with the name of jar instead of `artifactid`)

As another note, for integration tests `failsafe` searches by default for class files ending in `IT` (integration test).