# Running Cucumber + SpringBootTest in an executable test JAR

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, cucumber

I have a requirement to run the Software Qualification Tests of my project as an **executable JAR**. I'm using *Cucumber* along with *SpringBootTests* for the tests and used *maven-assembly-plugin* to create the executable JAR.
I have created a sample project ([link](https://github.com/AdityaAbinash-TomTom/cucumber-spring-executable-tests) to GitHub) where I have implemented what I want to do.

In the project, I am able to:

1. Execute `CucumberMainTest`, which is simple runner that can be executed from an IDE

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources/features",
    glue = "example/cucumberspringexecutabletests/steps")
public class CucumberMainTest {
}
```

2. Execute `MainTest` from the IDE, which is the *main* class

```
import io.cucumber.core.cli.Main;

public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] defaultArgs = {
            "--glue", "example/cucumberspringexecutabletests/steps",
            "classpath:features",
            "--plugin", "pretty"
        };

        Main.main(defaultArgs);
    }
}
```

But, I'm not able to achieve my main goal of executing the *main* class from an executable JAR. When I try to execute the JAR, after packaging, I get an error.

Command used:

```
java -jar .\target\cucumber-spring-executable-tests-3.1.3-test-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Error:

```
Scenario: As a developer, I want to run an executable test jar # features/spring.feature:3
  Given the test jar is built                                  # example.cucumberspringexecutabletests.steps.MyStepDefs.MyStepDefs()                              
      io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: class example.cucumberspringexecutabletests.steps.MyStepDefs does not have a public zero-argument constructor.
                                                                                                                                                                  
To use dependency injection add an other ObjectFactory implementation such as:                                                                                    
 * cucumber-picocontainer                                                                                                                                         
 * cucumber-spring                                                                                                                                                
 * cucumber-jakarta-cdi                                                                                                                                           
 * ...etc                                                                                                                                                         

        at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:57)
        at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45)
        at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
        at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:84)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:56)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:51)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:84)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$executePickle$6(Runtime.java:107)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$executePickle$7(Runtime.java:107)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:235)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$runFeatures$3(Runtime.java:89)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:200)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1602)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.runFeatures(Runtime.java:90)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$0(Runtime.java:78)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runFeatures$6(CucumberExecutionContext.java:148)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.execute(CucumberExecutionContext.java:163)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runFeatures(CucumberExecutionContext.java:146)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:78)
        at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:87)
        at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:30)
        at example.cucumberspringexecutabletests.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: example.cucumberspringexecutabletests.steps.MyStepDefs.<init>()
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3585)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2271)
        at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:52)
        ... 40 more

  When the test jar is executed                                # example.cucumberspringexecutabletests.steps.MyStepDefs.when()
  Then the test jar prints "Hello World"                       # example.cucumberspringexecutabletests.steps.MyStepDefs.then()

Failed scenarios:
classpath:features/spring.feature:3 # As a developer, I want to run an executable test jar

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
3 Steps (1 failed, 2 skipped)
0m0.183s


io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: class example.cucumberspringexecutabletests.steps.MyStepDefs does not have a public zero-argument constructor.

To use dependency injection add an other ObjectFactory implementation such as:
 * cucumber-picocontainer
 * cucumber-spring
 * cucumber-jakarta-cdi
 * ...etc
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$0(Runtime.java:78)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runFeatures$6(CucumberExecutionContext.java:148)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.execute(CucumberExecutionContext.java:163)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runFeatures(CucumberExecutionContext.java:146)
        at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:78)
        at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:87)
        at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:30)
        at example.cucumberspringexecutabletests.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: example.cucumberspringexecutabletests.steps.MyStepDefs.<init>()
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3585)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2271)
        at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:52)
        ... 40 more
```

It seems like the Spring context is not getting initialized/invoked. I looked into the following links to reach this point but looks like some configuration is still missing:

- [Running Cucumber from command line](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?lang=java#running-cucumber)
- [Running spring tests from executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52188683/running-spring-tests-from-executable-jar)

Right now the only way it works using the executable JAR is to remove any Autowiring.

Comment: What is the full stacktrace?

Comment: I have added the full stacktrace to the post.

Comment: Looks like you're not correctly assembling your executable jar file. You need to merge the files from `META-INF/services`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47310215/merging-meta-inf-services-files-with-maven-assembly-plugin

Comment: Thanks, @M.P.Korstanje for looking into this, but this still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you verify that the contents of `META-INF/services` is correct?

Comment: Yes, I see a lot of new classes being added in spring.factories, and I also see

"""# PropertySource Loaders
org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourceLoader=\
org.springframework.boot.env.PropertiesPropertySourceLoader,\
org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader"""

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Seeing lots of classes being added does not mean that what is being added is correct. These files must be merged - not overwritten.

Comment: I'm not sure what I should be looking for. Could you please provide me with some links to documentation related to this stuff?
I've never worked on this part of Spring.

Comment: You are merging multiple jar files into one. Some files in the jars may have identical names but different content. This content should be merged. You should be looking for a effect called clobbering.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clobbering

Comment: If you are not familiar with how Jar files are structured then consider using the Spring Boot Maven plugin to create a jar file for you. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins.maven This will package the jar in a way that is supported and understood by Spring. It has it's limitations, Cucumber only understands it partially. But if you have only a single module, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @M.P.Korstanje, I'll have a look.